# Android studio- Getting data from AsynTask to main thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm making an app that shows tables of soccer leagues using an external API.
I'm working with a fragment, which contains a recyclerview (To show the league table), and i use an AsyncTask to get the actual data from the web. I have 2 problems with that:

1. In the onCreateView method of the fragment, i'm setting the recyclerview. I put the adapter as a local variable, and then, inside the onPostExecute method in the AsyncTask, i pass the results (The table data. In here, it's an array of TeamLeagueStandings), to the adapter. Then, the problem is that the adapter for some reason stays null, and i can't understand why.
2. While it's getting the data, i want it to show the progressBar, and in the AsyncTask methods, onPreExecute and onPostExecute, i change the visibility value of the progress bar. For some reason, the progress bar isn't showing up at all. Why is it happening?

This is the Fragment which contains recyclerview (to show the table itself), and inside it- the AsyncTask (DownloadTask):

```
 public class TableStandingsFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String LEAGUETOLAUNCH = "league";
    private TeamAdapter adapter;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private String league;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public TableStandingsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static TableStandingsFragment newInstance(String param1) {
        TableStandingsFragment fragment = new TableStandingsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(LEAGUETOLAUNCH, param1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Gets the argument of the fragment. This will tell us which league table to show
        //using the method "GeturlTeamsByArg", which gives the URL, and then using AsyncTask to get
        //the actual data, with the given url.
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            league = getArguments().getString(LEAGUETOLAUNCH);
        }
    }



    public URL GeturlTeamsByArg() {

        //Returns the correct URL of the required league table, depends on the variable "league"

        URL url=null;
        if (league == "" || league == null)
            return null;
        switch (league) {
            case ("Premier League"):
                url = League_standings.GetPLQuery();
                break;
            case ("Football League Championship"):
                url = League_standings.GetChampionshipQuery();
                break;
            case ("Eredvise"):
                url = League_standings.GetEredviseQuery();
                break;
            case ("Ligue 1"):
                url = League_standings.GetLigue1Query();
                break;
            case ("Ligue 2"):
                url = League_standings.GetLigue2Query();
                break;
            case ("Bundesliga"):
                url = League_standings.GetBundesligaQuery();
                break;
            case ("2. Bundesliga"):
                url = League_standings.GetSecBundesligaQuery();
                break;
            case ("Primera División"):
                url = League_standings.GetSpanishQuery();
                break;
            case ("Serie A"):
                url = League_standings.GetSeriaAQuery();
                break;
            case ("Primeira Liga"):
                url = League_standings.GetPortugeseQuery();
                break;
        }
        return  url;
    }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           // StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            //StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recyclerview, container, false);
            progressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            DownloadTask downloadTask=new DownloadTask();
            try{
                downloadTask.execute(GeturlTeamsByArg());
                RecyclerView recyclerView =  (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyler_teams);
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpaceItemDecorator(30));
                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
                layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("error",e.toString());
            }




            return v;
        }


    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }
    class VerticalSpaceItemDecorator extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

        private final int spacer;

        public VerticalSpaceItemDecorator(int spacer) {
            this.spacer = spacer;
        }

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
            outRect.bottom = spacer;
        }
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }



    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, TeamLeagueStandings[]> {

        // COMPLETED (26) Override onPreExecute to set the loading indicator to visible
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
           progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected TeamLeagueStandings[] doInBackground(URL... params) {
            URL searchUrl = params[0];
            TeamLeagueStandings[] results = null;
            try {
                results = League_standings.LeagueStandingsArray(searchUrl);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(TeamLeagueStandings[] results) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            adapter=new TeamAdapter(results);

        }
    }
  }
```

This is the class where i'm getting the actual data and deal with the JSON:

```
public class League_standings {

//League codes in the url
private final static int PLCODE = 445;
private final static int CHAMPIONSHIPCODE = 446;
private final static int EREDVISECODE = 449;
private final static int LIGUE1CODE = 450;
private final static int LIGUE2CODE = 451;
private final static int BUNDESLIGACODE = 452;
private final static int SECBUNDESLIGACODE = 453;
private final static int SPANISHCODE = 455;
private final static int SERIAACODE = 456;
private final static int PORTUGESECODE = 457;
private static String nationCode = "";
private static String querystr = "";
private static URL url = null;
private static TeamLeagueStandings[] teams;


public static URL GetPLQuery() {
    // Returns the full URL of the search query combined with the PL code.
    nationCode = Integer.toString(PLCODE);
    querystr = "competitions/" + nationCode + "/leagueTable";
    url = Data.BuildUrl(querystr);
    return url;
}

public static URL GetChampionshipQuery() {
    // Returns the full URL of the search query combined with the championship code.
    nationCode = Integer.toString(CHAMPIONSHIPCODE);
    querystr = "competitions/" + nationCode + "/leagueTable";
    url = Data.BuildUrl(querystr);
    return url;
}

public static URL GetEredviseQuery() {
    // Returns the full URL of the search query combined with the eredvise code.
    nationCode = Integer.toString(EREDVISECODE);
    querystr = "competitions/" + nationCode + "/leagueTable";
    url = Data.BuildUrl(querystr);
    return url;
}

public static URL GetLigue1Query() {
    // Returns the full URL of the search query combined with the ligue1 code.
    nationCode = Integer.toString(LIGUE1CODE);
    querystr = "competitions/" + nationCode + "/leagueTable";
    url = Data.BuildUrl(querystr);
    return url;
}

public static URL GetLigue2Query() {
    // Returns the full URL of the search query combined with the ligue2 code.
    nationCode = Integer.toString(LIGUE2CODE);
    querystr = "competitions/" + nationCode + "/leagueTable";
    url = Data.BuildUrl(querystr);
    return url;
}

public static URL GetBundesligaQuery() {
    // Returns the full URL of the search query combined with the bundesliga code.
    nationCode = Integer.toString(BUNDESLIGACODE);
    querystr = "competitions/" + nationCode + "/leagueTable";
    url = Data.BuildUrl(querystr);
    return url;
}

public static URL GetSecBundesligaQuery() {
    // Returns the full URL of the search query combined with the second bundesliga code.
    nationCode = Integer.toString(SECBUNDESLIGACODE);
    querystr = "competitions/" + nationCode + "/leagueTable";
    url = Data.BuildUrl(querystr);
    return url;
}

public static URL GetSpanishQuery() {
    // Returns the full URL of the search query combined with the Spanish league code.
    nationCode = Integer.toString(SPANISHCODE);
    querystr = "competitions/" + nationCode + "/leagueTable";
    url = Data.BuildUrl(querystr);
    return url;
}

public static URL GetSeriaAQuery() {
    // Returns the full URL of the search query combined with the seria A code.
    nationCode = Integer.toString(SERIAACODE);
    querystr = "competitions/" + nationCode + "/leagueTable";
    url = Data.BuildUrl(querystr);
    return url;
}

public static URL GetPortugeseQuery() {
    // Returns the full URL of the search query combined with the Portugese league code.
    nationCode = Integer.toString(PORTUGESECODE);
    querystr = "competitions/" + nationCode + "/leagueTable";
    url = Data.BuildUrl(querystr);
    return url;
}


public static TeamLeagueStandings[] LeagueStandingsArray(URL url) throws IOException, JSONException {

    //Gets the full url of the requested league table, should look like: 
    //"http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/445/leagueTable"
    //Processing the JSON data from the API, then returns an array which 
    //contains the teams of the league
    //that was requested, in THE ORDER OF THE TABLE!!!

    String results = Data.GetResponseFromHttpUrl(url);
    JSONObject resultsJSON = new JSONObject(results);
    JSONArray teamsJson = resultsJSON.getJSONArray("standing");
    int length = teamsJson.length();
    teams = new TeamLeagueStandings[length];
    // name,games,wins,draws,losses,GD,points, pic
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {


        JSONObject object = teamsJson.getJSONObject((i));
        TeamLeagueStandings team = new TeamLeagueStandings();
        team.setPlace(Integer.toString(object.getInt("position")));
        team.setTeamName(object.getString("teamName"));
        team.setCurGames(Integer.toString(object.getInt("playedGames")));
        team.setWins(Integer.toString(object.getInt("wins")));
        team.setDraws(Integer.toString(object.getInt("draws")));
        team.setLosses(Integer.toString(object.getInt("losses")));
        team.setGoalDifference(Integer.toString(object.getInt("goalDifference")));
        team.setPoints(Integer.toString(object.getInt("points")));
        team.setImgString(object.getString("crestURI"));
        if (team.getTeamName().toLowerCase().contains("FC".toLowerCase())) {
            team.setTeamName(team.getTeamName().replace("FC", ""));
        }
        if (team.getTeamName().endsWith(" ")) {
            team.setTeamName(StringUtils.strip(team.getTeamName()));

        }
        if (team.getTeamName().length() > 12) {
            String name = team.getTeamName();
            for (int j = 12; j < name.length(); j++) {
                char c = name.charAt(j);
                if (c == ' ') {
                    name = name.substring(0, j) + "\n" + name.substring(j + 1);
                    team.setTeamName(name);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        teams[i] = team;
    }

    return teams;
}
```

}

Thanks!! :)

Comment: Try to create recyclerview and its adapter before executing asynctask. In your case right now you can get response from server before they are initlialized

Comment: I changed it a little bit. Now i'm dealing with the recyclerview only in onPostExecute, and in onCreateView, i'm just calling the AsyncTask, and it's working great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use get data onProgressUpdate func.. during doinBackground 
Example:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            onProgressUpdate();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            // here you can get data from MainThread
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I changed it a little bit. Now i'm dealing with the recyclerview only in onPostExecute, and in onCreateView, i'm just calling the AsyncTask, and it's working great. Thanks!